# Convert Dataframe columns to ndarray

Tags: python, pandas

If I have a dataframe where each column contains a list

```
a    b
[]   []
[]   []
.    .
.    .
.    .
```

calling `df.values` turns the dataframe into an ndarray, but leaves the sublists as lists. Is there a way to make all sublists ndarrays as well?

Thanks

Comment: Just to be clear, you're aware that storing lists and numpy arrays as elements of Series is not recommended?

Comment: No, I'm fairly new to this language. I am doing this for a project I have

Comment: Hmmm.... Yes, I'd like to know what's *really* going on here before answering. How did you get this odd DataFrame in the first place and what are you trying to do?

Comment: Well the thought is, for every entry we have a list of items and a corresponding list of how many times an item has been used.

Comment: I agree with @LondonRob, this feels fundamentally wrong. You are probably using pandas in the wrong way if you want this.

Comment: Where does the DataFrame come from? Are you perhaps reading in a CSV incorrectly? Or some other file format? There's no use case that could require such a set up.